# Delete a vertex of polygon google maps API v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

So there are many posts on how to delete the vertex of a google maps polygon.  None of them have worked for me - this may be due to the outdated API's they reference.  I am trying to limit the number of points a user can create on a polygon.  If they create more than a certain number of points I would like to either programmatically trigger the 'undo' functionality built into google maps or have some way of deleting the last vertex created.

When I create the initial polygon for a user to work with I add this event listener in:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(myPolygon.getPath(), 'insert_at', function(event){
  var numPoints = myPolygon.getPath().length;

  if(numPoints == 5){
    myPolygon.getPath().removeAt(4);
  }
});
```

This ends up removing a point from the polygon (NOT necessarily the last point created).  Sometimes it causes the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'b' of undefined.

I have attempted using a 'click' listener on the polygon, but the click event does not fire when a user creates a new vertex.  It only fires when the actual polygon shaped is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your are using an path with auto-completition(the first LatLng is not equal to the last LatLng)

There seems to be a bug when you try to remove the last LatLng from an autocompleted path.

This bug doesn't prevent you from removing the point, the error occurs later(I guess when the API updates  the UI for the editable polygon).
You may simply use a try/catch-statement to bypass this error.

Related to the position of the removed point: a newly created point will not be inserted at the end of the path, it will be inserted between the points where it's placed.
When you insert a point between point1(index 0) and point2(index 1) the newly created point will have the index 1.

You may use  the first argument of the callback to retrieve this index.

Summary:

---

```
google.maps.event.addListener(myPolygon.getPath(), 'insert_at', function(index){
  if(this.getLength() > 4){
    try{
      this.removeAt(index);
    }catch(e){}
  }
});
```

Comment: That was my problem.  The auto-completed polygons do not work correctly when removing points, but it works fine as long as the last point is equal to the first point.  http://jsbin.com/wipuv/2/edit does not work, while http://jsbin.com/wipuv/3/edit does work.

Comment: Sorry I have to take that back.  If the first point is equal to the last point it still won't work if someone chooses to move the first or last point during editing.  e.g.  The triangles in my links have 4 points and the error is thrown when someone moves the first/last point then inserts a new point in between them.

Comment: Works like a charm when I catch the error.  Thanks for your insight.  :)